# Views are not appearing in emulator as designed in layout

Tags: android, layout

I am using `relative layout` for my activity. I have designed my `layout` like this.

[image: Layout that I have designed]

But when I run the app in `emulator` the `components` do not appear in the same place as I have designed in my `layout`. I can't figure out why this is happening. Please check my `layout` xml code below and let me know if you have any solution for my problem.

[image: After running on emulator]

**Layout xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/foodpic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foodname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foodpic"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/foodprice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="price" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minus"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodname"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/foodpic"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="-" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/foodname"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/minus"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/plus"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addtocart"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/foodprice"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart_black_24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your image took that space and move the editText and other views to right. It's because you set the `imageWidth` to `wrap_content`. One thing you can do here is to set a fixed size to your `ImageView`.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I didn't know about accepting someone's answer.